# wifi driver disappears every time on updating ubuntu and restarting

Tags: wireless, 18.04

when I install the updates and restart the machine the wifi driver is gone.
In system setting no wifi driver is found.
what could be the possible reason?
how can i install the wifi driver?(with and without internet)

Please Help me!!!

Comment: How are you installing driver?

Comment: i am running the WiFi file from the restricted folder from the bootable drive.

Comment: bcmwl-kernel-source?  Broadcom proprietary

Comment: I am new to Linux but yes those were proprietary files. One was wifi and one was kernel related

Comment: Open a terminal window and post results for `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: SecureBoot disabled